# C# - String was not recognized as valid datetime

Tags: c#, string, exception, datetime

I have the following method in order to verify whether a string is a valid datetime:

```
public bool isDate(string date)
        {
            bool check = false;

            try
            {
                DateTime converted_date = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
                check = true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                check = false;
            }
            return check;
        }
```

Now, the exception "String was not recognized as valid datetime" is caught whenever I try to pass a string like this:

"12/31/2013 12:00:00 AM"

I cannot understand why this is happening.  Can someone help me solve this please?

Comment: What's wrong with [`DateTime.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely your current culture settings are different from the format date is provided in. You can try specifying the culture explicitly:

```
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-US"); // or whatever culture you want
Convert.ToDateTime(date, culture);
```

Comment: Thanks Andrei :)  I am experimenting a little bit to see which one gets the desired result.  Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks Andrei :)  I formatted the date as follows: DateTime date = (DateTime)DatePicker_ExpiryDate.Value;
                string expiry_date = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH':'mm':'ss");  It now works perfectly :)

Comment: @Matthew, well, specifying exact format of the date is the other possible way. But still I would recommend you to check out your culture settings - it is rather strange that your code did not work initially.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of the try/catch block, try the built in TryParse method in the DateTime class.  It takes your string as a parameter and if it converts successfully it will place the value in the "result" variable.  It returns a boolean value representing whether it worked or not.

```
public bool isDate(string date)
{
    var result = new DateTime();

    return DateTime.TryParse(date, out result);
}
```

Comment: Combine this with Andrei's answer

Comment: Thanks :)  I am experimenting.  I will let you know if it works

Comment: I formatted the date using the following convension:  DateTime date = (DateTime)DatePicker_ExpiryDate.Value;
                string expiry_date = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH':'mm':'ss");

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `DateTime.TryParseExact` and pass a format string (eg. `MM/dd/yy H:mm:ss zzz`, see more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)) to check if the date has a specific format.